# Компьютер постоянно перезагружается при установке Windows 10 и установка не выпполняется

Tags: windows-10, установка, iso-образ, altlinux

Появилась проблема при установке Windows 10 вместо Linux. На пк (друга) был установлен ALT Linux и он захотел сменить его на Windows. Я сделал загрузочную флешку через утилиту от Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download . Далее выбрал эту флешку в биосе (загрузка с USB была включена) и перезагрузил пк. После запуска появляется значок Windows и загрузки, но потом пк перезагружается и это снова повторяется. Диск на Linux разделён не был, т.к. планировалась установка винды не как 2й ос, а вместо Linux. Пробовали вставлять флешку и в USB 2.0, и в USB 3.0 - тоже самое. На виртуальной машине загрузка началась, но не завершилась (но это скорее проблемы вм, т.к. она не поддерживает загрузку с флешки и запустил я её обходным путём). Может стоит записывать образ на флешку через другие программы (rufus) и есть ли смысл создать LIVE версию Windows и пробовать что-то делать через неё?